# Proximal operator of Adaptive Elastic Net

Tags: regression, regularization, loss-functions, elastic-net, coordinate-descent

I would like to learn how to find the proximal operator of the Adaptive Elastic Net, from DOI: 10.1214/08-AOS625 "ON THE ADAPTIVE ELASTIC-NET WITH A DIVERGING NUMBER OF PARAMETERS" by HUI ZOU and HAO HELEN ZHANG.

I saw that Lasso has a simple formula for the proximal operator and soft thresholding. I would like to know if it is possible to do the same with the adaptive elastic net penalty.

$$
\text{minimize } L(\beta) = \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_i - \beta_0 - \sum_{j=1}^{p} x_{ij}\beta_j)^2 + \lambda \left(\alpha \sum_{j=1}^{p} |\beta_j| + \frac{1-\alpha}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{p} \hat{w_j}*\beta_j^2\right)  
$$

Where i use a ridge regression as the initial estimate of betas and use them to compute the adaptive weights $$ \hat{w} = 1 / |\hat{\beta}| $$

My intention is to use this penalty with a coordinate descent algotithm with Coordinate-wise Updates where it estmates one beta while keeping the others fixed.